# Executing Ping for secured host URLs

Tags: macos, cocoa, terminal, ping

I am facing a strange issue with PING utility. When I execute the PING command on my terminal to test the connectivity for my host, it works fine on Ethernet but not on WiFi. But I am able to access the host on WiFi using my application. The only difference is I am using HTTPS when connecting host from my application. Now, when I prefix the host with HTTPS:// I get "Unknown host" error on terminal. Any idea what could be wrong? And how to execute Ping on a secured server like this?

```
ping -c10 -b en1 test.retail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding about what ping is doing. **Ping is sending ICMP echo request packets and waits for the corresponding response. ICMP is a completely different network protocol from TCP, which is used for HTTPS.**

A host can be responding to HTTPS connection attempts but not respond to ping (e.g. because a firewall on the host itself or somewhere on the way between you and the host you're trying to ping drops ICMP echo request packets or responses), and vice versa (e.g. because the host is not running a web server, or access to it is restricted/firewalled).

Ping is the right tool to see if you can reach a host that is configured to respond to ICMP echo request packets (if you can reasonably assume that there's no firewall in between you and the host, or on the host, filtering out this type of network traffic), and to determine the response time between you and the host.

However, if you want to test if a host is responding on a certain TCP port (e.g. port 80 for a HTTP web server, or 443 for an HTTPS web server), you can use Telnet in Terminal:

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

If there is a server listening on that TCP port, you'll see something like:

```
Trying 173.194.69.106...
Connected to www.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If it's a web server, you can then even talk HTTP to it if you like to:

```
GET /
```

And it'll reply:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
(...)
```

Now that we have this out of the way, the question remains why your host does respond to ping through Ethernet, but not through Wi-Fi.

**One reason could be that many networks permit unrestricted access to all internal hosts when using a wired Ethernet connection, but have a firewall in place that restricts connections from the wireless network to hosts on the LAN or DMZ.**

Where is the host you're trying to ping located? And how is network traffic routed from the Ethernet and Wi-Fi networks to your host?

Comment: Thank you for such an explanation. And you are right, the host I am trying to reach is actually a Virtual IP and with firewall settings.